# Stored Procedure Dynamic Order By

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-order-by

Hi fellow stackoverflow members,

I have a pressing question here.

I am currently developing a mini web application with a `GridView`. The `GridView` must be able to perform `multi column` sorting dynamically. Whenever user click on the different columns, my C# app will parse the columns and sort order `asc/desc` to the stored procedure to perform retrieval of records. As such, my SP must be able to handle the inputs dynamically.

I don't wish to use dynamic SQL and wish to stick to PL/SQL queries.

Here's a sample of my code,

```
SELECT ID,NAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID='123' ORDER BY ID ASC, NAME DESC;
```

This part, `ORDER BY ID ASC, NAME DESC` must be dynamic. I wish to formulate this part based on the parameters passed in from my application.

I am currently messing around with DECODE function and CASE function and have mixed results as i am only able to handle 1 parameter input. I need to be able to handle multiple column sorting if users click on multiple columns on my GridView.

This part should be dynamic and able to handle multiple column sorting.

`ORDER BY ID ASC, NAME DESC, CLASS ASC` ... and so on and so forth .

Fellow members please point me in the right direction. Thanks!

> 1) Don't wish to use dynamic sql and achieve the above in PL/SQL.
>
> 2) Parameters input customizable, ok with anything on front end. Need
>   help with the SP.

Regards,
TP

Comment: Hi guys, my asc/desc have to be dynamic too.
I do not know how many columns the user wants to sort at runtime.
The number of columns to order by is based on what columns the user clicks...

Answer (score 4):

You can pass Parameter for that  (@SortIndex)

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 1 THEN ID END ASC,
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 2 THEN NAME END DESC
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 3 THEN Title END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the

```
DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(50)
```

this two arguments as an input parameter for Stored procedure

Try the following `CASE` condition as:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'ASC' THEN @ColumnName END ASC,
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'DESC' THEN @ColumnName END DESC
```

Comment: On which version of Sql Server?

Comment: In this case, it only works for single column sort right?
Can it handle multiple column sorting? Eg. order by ID ASC, NAME DESC?
Or do i have to hardcore the above solution 3 times to sort 3 columns?

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant, but it should work. Supply a code number and sort accordingly:

```
ORDER BY CASE myparam 
         WHEN  1 THEN col1 ASC 
         WHEN -1 THEN col1 DESC
         WHEN  2 THEN col2 ASC 
         WHEN -2 THEN col2 ASC
         END;
```

Comment: Does this work for multiple column sorting?
To my understanding this only works for one parameter/column sorting right?

Comment: You could extend it to multiple columns (`WHEN -x THEN col1||col2`), but it will lead to a combinatorial explosion, as there are 2n! possibilities to order n columns (12 for 3 columns, 240 for 5, 7 mio for 10...)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_DETAILS (ORDER_TYPE1   IN VARCHAR2(5)
                         ORDER_TYPE2   IN VARCHAR2(5)
                                         ORDER_FIELD1 IN VARCHAR2(5) 
                                         ORDER_FIELD2  IN VARCHAR2(5)
                     V_ID         IN VARCHAR2(5)
                                         OUTPUT_DATA  OUT REF_CURSOR)
    IS
BEGIN 

OPEN OUTPUT_DATA FOR 
SELECT ID,NAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID=V_ID ORDER BY ORDER_FIELD1 ORDER_TYPE1, ORDER_FIELD2 ORDER_TYPE2;

END GET_DETAILS;
```

ORDER_TYPE1,ORDER_TYPE2,ORDER_FIELD1 etc are inputs
The output of this procedure will be the set of records as you want